# Intersection of a Infinite Collection of Sets - null set or infinity?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let's say we have a collection of sets $\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty A_i$ where $A_i=[i,\infty]$. In other words:

$$ \bigcap_{i=1}^\infty A_i = [1,\infty] \cap [2,\infty] \cap [3,\infty] \cap ... [\infty,\infty] $$

I was thinking that there is no intersection between each of these sets $\varnothing$. However, I was thinking it could also be {$\infty$}.

Which evaluation is correct? What is infinity anyway? Is it some really high number that ends somewhere, or does it keep on going.....forever, with no ending.

Comment: {∅}? Hopefully you mean ∅

Comment: Ah yes, that doesn't make too much sense does it. Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every $A_i$ contains $\infty$. For any finite $n\in \mathbb{N}$ the set $A_{n+1}$ does not contain $n$. Hence the intersection contains only $\infty$. In the extended reals you can for all intents and purposes treat infinity as an actual number.

Comment: But if these sets go on forever, then they shouldn't have any intersection at all?

Comment: Only if infinity is not considered to be part of your intervals, which is usually how we look at it. But, if each set contains infinity, it is in there.

Comment: Although it does not make formal sense, think of every set having upper bound of infinity.

Comment: I can live with that!